# Send FCM message to a device without authenticate the sender possible?

Tags: java, authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

this might be a strange question but:

I have an external server that needs to send notifications to an Android and iOS device, as firebase is the only way to go with background notifications I need to use it.

Now, the server is HIGHLY secure, NO incoming connection from ANY IP are allowed. I still need to send FCM messages. In the documentation we have to authenticate the sender (This is clearly not possible, as this would require a bidrectional connection).

Is there a possibility to send messages without any authentication? Like a public POST?

Or if not. Is there a way, that I can reuse the same private key to authenticate, so that I still can fire and forget without the need of an incoming connection?

For those interested why:
We only send a data notification (trigger) that something MIGHT have changed, the real secure connection happens in the background via seperate channels and without firebase. Firebase is just the trigger for changes to avoid polling the backend

EDIT:

Can this code be actually uses as `fire-and-forget`:

```
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE);

    FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);


    //...Generate message


    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the legacy protocol for sending messages, you can authenticate by providing the static FCM server key in the `Authorization` header of the request. See the documentation on [authorizing legacy protocol send requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize-legacy-protocol-send-requests) for more information.

While it is recommended that new applications use the versioned (currently `v1`) API, there are no plans to retire the legacy API.

---

From a quick look at the documentation on [providing credentials manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#provide-credentials-manually), it looks like you can also use pre-generated service account credentials to authenticate. This would also not require any dynamic authentication at runtime.

Comment: Okay, I assumed legacy goes hand in hand with retirement anytime soon. So you are saying we are safe to use it? What I don't understand is your second part. Of course I read the documentation but it says we have to "mint the short living access token", so I need an incoming connection for the token, and the credentials are not static or am I wrong here?

Comment: Ah, you're right: you'll indeed need to mint an access token even when using service credentials. I never realized the Admin SDK does that behind the scenes for me.